# How can Dimensions be included in the API call object?

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

See - https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/189

Looking to see if anyone has worked around this?

Answer (score 0):

Fix found at https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/189#issuecomment-47358326

Excerpt:

> Found my own issue I think. I was including "dimension" on the call obj instead of "dimensions".